# Loading information from Array into ChartJS, Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Tags: javascript, echarts

this is my first time posting here, so I apologize in advanced if I missed something I needed to include.

I am trying to create a donut chart with data from a php file, and even though the array loads and is visible in the console log, the following error is shown.

> Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

```
         <div id="trafficChart" style="min-height: 400px;" class="echart"></div>

         
         <script>

          var Name = [];
          var Q_Sold = [];

          $(document).ready(function(){
              $.ajax({
                url: "https://host-3:8890/data.php",
                method: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                   Name = [];
                   Q_Sold = [];

                  for(var i in data) {
                    Name.push(data[i].Name);
                    Q_Sold.push(data[i].Q_Sold);
                  }

                  

                },
                error: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                }
              });
            });



            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
              echarts.init(document.querySelector("#trafficChart")).setOption({
                tooltip: {
                  trigger: 'item'
                },
                legend: {
                  top: '5%',
                  left: 'center'
                },
                series: [{
                  name: 'Access From',
                  type: 'pie',
                  radius: ['40%', '70%'],
                  avoidLabelOverlap: false,
                  label: {
                    show: false,
                    position: 'center'
                  },
                  emphasis: {
                    label: {
                      show: true,
                      fontSize: '18',
                      fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }
                  },
                  labelLine: {
                    show: false
                  },
                  data: [{
                    value: Q_Sold,
                    name: Name
                  }]
                }],
                 
                });
            });

          </script>

        </div>
      </div>
```

However if I change the data values from

```
data: [{
    value: Q_Sold,
    name: Name
  }]
```

To

```
data: [{
    value: 1000,
    name: "Name"
  }]
```

The Chart renders perfectly fine. I have no clue to what the problem might be.

Comment: can you post the data you receive from the server (e.g. by `console.log`)?.  Also make sure to call the initialization of your graph after the ajax call completes. The `DOMContentLoaded` will run before the ajax call completes, thus the chart is being initialized with empty arrays.

Comment: are you using Chart.JS or Apache eCharts ? if Chart.JS, please update the tags on this post, if eCharts, please update the Title on this post. Maybe also add jquery tag as I think this may be related to the promise resolution from jquery ajax success. I have seen where you can log the result to the console, yet you cannot use the result yet as the promise is not yet resolved. Maybe try adding `async: true,` to your jquery ajax call?